# implementing image swap animation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to implement the animation over the thumbnails of the portfolio section as shown in the following template.

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/#

I had planned to implement that by swapping the image src using Jquery on mouseenter() and mouseleave().

```
            $(".pictures .thumbnail").mouseenter ( function () {
                $(this).attr("src","glass.png");
            });
```

I am unable to find a way of storing the src of the original thumbnail the mouse is pointing at, so that i can use it on the mouseleave() function.

html code for the thumbnails, just in case.

```
<div class = "pictures ">
            <div class = "container ">
                <div >

                    <center><b><text>PORTFOLIO</text></b></center>
                </div>
                <div class = "pics">
                  <div class = "column">
                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img src = "cabin.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img src = "cake.png">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class = "column">
                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img src = "circus.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img src = "game.png">
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "column">
                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img src = "safe.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img src = "submarine.png">
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any ideas on how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The theme didn't use javascript to do this.

Comment: i am trying to implement the animation on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as expected:

```
$('.pictures .thumbnail img').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event){
    var originalimage = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
    $(this).attr("data-src", originalimage);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gwkyupup/5/

Answer (score 1):

add `data` attribute on your `<img>` elements.

```
<div class="thumbnail">
   <img data-src="cabin.png" src="cabin.png" alt="" />
</div>

$(".pictures .thumbnail").mouseenter ( function () {
      $(this).find('img').attr("src","glass.png");
});

$(".pictures .thumbnail").mouseleave ( function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.find('img').attr("src", $this.find('img').attr("data-src");
});
```

Comment: you're setting 'src' attribute to the div.thumbnail, you should refer to its `<img>` child i.e. `$(this).find('img').attr('src','...')` ...